# Error when calling Executable from Tkinter

Tags: python, c, user-interface, tkinter

I have a Executable named `learn` after compiling my program `vv.c` in linux.I am using Tkinter (python-Tk) for making My GUI.But When running my executable code.It reached a error message "sh :1 : learn :not found " where -t -c -b are parametes passing to executable.

```
else:
        if self.binaryFeature == 0:
        cmd = "learn" + "-t " + self.type + " -c "\
                      + self.C + " " + self.e2.get() + " " + self.e3.get()
        else:
        cmd = "learn" + "-t " + self.type + " -c "\
                          + self.C + " -b 1 " + self.e2.get()\
                          + " " + self.e3.get()
        output_string = commands.getoutput(cmd)
        self.text.insert(INSERT, output_string+"\n","CprogramOutput")
```

is it any error in commands for executing ?please help me ..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put a space before "-t":

```
cmd = "learn" + " -t " + self.type + " -c "\
                  + self.C + " " + self.e2.get() + " " + self.e3.get()
```

currently the shell evaluates the command as `learn-t` rather than `learn -t`.

Comment: You should check to see if `learn` is in your path. You could also just explicitly put the full path in the script.

Comment: If the problem is solved, you should mark the post as the correct answer.